# Encoding issue : how to restore the original code

Tags: input-encodings

Opening a .tex file in any text editor (TexShop, Atom, ...) gives me  the ugly

> %PDF-1.5
>   %ÐÔÅØ
>   3 0 obj
>   <<
>   /Length 2988
>   /Filter /FlateDecode
>   >
>   stream
>   xÚÍMwÛÆñî_[Á÷Lx¿ë=;Ø®ìŒ, Ð ¶ÕþùÎì,@ZJc§œÅ`vŸ¿\%,ùñ;rýáÝ£'/žMË:yw8ecmfOÞ­÷é?ÖŠeñ¯ÅR²<ív¥0éª­újUÔŽ{ã÷Êvµ­ŸÚ6Ž;\ÏTMÕxçÒMY4KÜ*ëõâüÝË[)#¥PcNœjëyÂU&h\òÆsDqGÄO^(ÀÉ-Ç'7w:Yj

(these are just the first few lines). For the story behind,  the trouble is due to an unwary  application of a duplicate file finder.

I suspect some encoding problem here and fear there is no way back to the original content (the pdf file is undamaged). Do I only need to change encoding in the text editor or is the information irremediably lost ?

Sorry for the naive question. I keep close to my desktop to give more information/edit my post if needed, or change the location if not appropriate here.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What you've shown is the typical beginning of a PDF file. So the problem is not an encoding issue but the fact that somehow the .tex has been overwritten with the contents of a PDF file. It would be hard to recover a .tex file from this.

Comment: Argh, this is precisely what I feared. Perfectly coherent with the application of a duplicate file finder. Thanks a lot for the confirmation !